# Check if selector contains text (ie. is not media) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Is there a way to use jQuery to see if my selector is a text based field.

ie. When a user clicks an element, we check if it's an element that does contain text and not an image, video etc.

What would be the best way to achieve this in jQuery?

Comment: what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to test the element for its children to know if one of them contain a non-text element.

```
if ($(this).find("img,video,object").length==0) {
   alert("i am a text only element");
} else {
   alert("i am not a text only element");
}
```

And you might have to test the element itself if it can trigger the click event.

Answer (score 2):

You may combine the .text method and .html methods. If the result of both coincides than the node only contains plain text.

```
text = $('element').text();
code = $('element').html();
if (text == code && text != ''){
    console.log('text node');
}
```

Comment: How would this work with a empty elemet? i.e. a `p` tag with no content?

Comment: I added a liitle sample code to the answr to better illustrate it.

Comment: It will only work if the element does not have any child. A `ul` can contain many `li` elements with text only, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `tagName` property to find out what kind of dom element it is, for example;

```
var someElement = $('[some selector]');
console.log(someElement[0].tagName);
```

This will give you the element name (i.e. 'P' for a `<p>` element).

This could then be checked against an array of text elements to suit your needs

something like `var textElements = ["P", "H1", H2", "SPAN"]`

Comment: A p element may contain just images.

Comment: True, but if the OP has the click handler set up correctly then the dom element would be of type `img` and not `p`